# QComboBox Ignore Keyboard Input

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside

When the dropdown list for a `QComboBox` is open, keyboard input is used as a (not particularly smart) way of searching for elements. I want to disable this and propagate the handling of keyboard events to the parent widget. How does one go about this? I've tried reimplementing `keyPressEvent` in a subclass but apparently that doesn't work as that function isn't the one that gets called when there's keyboard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the popup is shown, it's the `QComboBox`'s view that recieves the events, not the box itself. You can place an event filter on it:

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

<...>

QComboBox box;
box.view()->installEventFilter(new Filter());
```